# Find and substitute semicolons which are not enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex

I have a multiline SQL script in which I need to replace the ";" characters which are at the end of the statements with the sequence "\nGO", leaving the ";" which are not at the end of the statements (the ones which are included in a string).

This is an example text

```
Insert into  TABLE1 (A, B) values ('a','b');
Insert into  TABLE2 (COMMAND) values ('/* Script generated at 20.04.2006 12:38:44 */

/* error_permissible = 955*/
Create Table map_encodekey
( privatekey VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL
);

/* error_permissible = 2260*/
Alter Table map_encodekey
  Add Constraint map_encodekey_pk
  Primary Key
   (privatekey);
');
```

So I need to replace only the two semicolons at the end of the two `INSERT` statements, leaving the ones in the string (wchich is a SQL command, but this doesn't matter).

I tried this, but it finds me all the ";"

```
/(?<!['])(?<![;])[;](?![;])(?!['])/g
```

What do you think the regex should look like?

Comment: Are there escape characters between the quotes, something like: `"foo \"bar\" qux"`?

Comment: @vks: no language, I will use this regex for some replaces in Notepad++.

Comment: @CommuSoft: the content of the string between two single quotes is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

You can use this and replace by `\nGO`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/35